# Set threshold number of processes in Linux

Tags: linux, process

If a process is run by multiple users, how can we set threshold (maximum) number of process has reached in Linux?

I have to set a warning when that threshold is reached. The processes can be run by multiple users. How can I calculate and set a value for this in Linux?

Comment: Do you mean one particular program, which is run by multiple users? There is difference between process and program, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999850/what-are-differentiates-between-a-program-an-executable-and-a-process

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question that I think you are asking.

One program can have multiple instances running. Each is a separate process. I'm not aware of any instance count that Linux makes available. So I don't think there is any setting that can be made to get Linux to enforce a maximum number of instances for you.

If user access to the program can be forced to come through a shell script or wrapper program, you have some options.

1) To just give a warning to users invoking the program who have reached or exceeded the number of instances, you could do a shell script that does something like

```
ps aux | grep TheProgramFileName > $InstanceCount
```

Then the script would compare to a maximum, and warn the user. But that won't stop anyone.

2) If the goal is to prevent multiple instances, that can be done by a shell script. Refer to [single instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220525/ensuring-a-single-instance-of-an-application-in-linux) and [preventing multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964391/preventing-multiple-process-instances-on-linux).

3) For maximum N instances, see [cooperative limiting](http://www.robertgamble.net/2011/04/cooperative-limiting-of-concurrent.html). But I don't think this can be done in a shell script.